# Undefined variable $selectName (Laravel)

Tags: laravel

I want to divide laravel pages into components, But when I am doing so it gives an error

> Undefined variable `$selectName`

Select Field Component (resources/views/components/atoms/select.blade.php)

```html
<select class="form-select" wire:model.lazy="{{ $selectName }}">
    <option value="" selected>Select</option>
    <option value="single">Single</option>
</select>
```

Error Field Component (resources/views/components/atoms/error.blade.php)

```html
@error("{{ $errorName }}")
    <div class="form-text text-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror
```

Parent Component (resources/views/components/molecules/select-field.blade.php)

```html
<div class="mb-3">
    <x-atoms.label />
    <x-atoms.select />
    <x-atoms.error />
</div>
```

Super Parent Component (resources/views/components/organisms/identity-form.blade.php)

```html
<div class="col">
    <x-molecules.select-field label="Marital Status" selectName="patient.marital_status" 
    errorName="patient.marital_status" message="$message" />
</div>
```

Select Component Class (app/View/Components/Atoms/Select.blade.php)

```php
<?php

namespace App\View\Components\Atoms;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class Select extends Component
{
    public $selectName;

    public function __construct($selectName)
    {
        $this->selectName = $selectName;
    }


    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.atoms.select');
    }
}
```

One more thing that I want to achieve is how do I print `{{ {{$message}} }}` in error component so that it will print error

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Use `@aware(['selectName'])` on top of the select component